# Is there any way to map a twilio call to the webhook that receives the call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am sending a call to a twilio number using twilio api, and in turn recording the sid of the call (e.g. `CAb90f709e54017969776d842873311746`). While the call is received in the webhook I have a different sid in the receiver end (e.g. `CA8d85ac8d8b169de8b0509c8585c6aaed` ). Is there any way to map the call sent to the call received ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Yes, you can! You should find that the call on the receiver end, which is the second or child leg of the call, has a parameter called `ParentCallSid` which will point back to the first leg of the call.

In your example, the `CallSid` will be `CA8d85ac8d8b169de8b0509c8585c6aaed` and the `ParentCallSid` will be `CAb90f709e54017969776d842873311746`.

Let me know if that helps at all.